# SSH and rsa authentication on mpich2

Tags: ssh, software-development, cluster

I'm trying to build a small cluster of pi's and am using `mpich2` to run parallel code. It appears `mpich2` has installed ok and I'm able to ssh into both (I'm starting with 2) pi's. However when I run a program using `mpich2` it makes me enter the passphrase for my `rsa` key pair 2 times then I have to enter the password for the other pi 3 times, each time having to press enter twice. According to [this](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton.htm) tutorial I should only have to enter those passwords once. However every time I run `mpich2` it makes me enter the passwords. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a SSH agent running that can remember your password. If `ps u -C ssh-agent` does not show any running processes, check your distribution documentation for installation details.

When you have installed it, I suggest you store the passphrase with an expiration date. For instance, store the default keys for an hour:

```
ssh-add -t 3600
```

If you need to store just a single key, or a key with an odd name, use something like:

```
ssh-add -t 3600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The currently active keys are visible with `ssh-add -l`. Now you can `ssh` into Pi's without constantly having to enter a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

did you enter any passphrase when generating your RSA keys? if yes, you have to create new keys, without a passphrase, otherwise you'll need to enter it everytime.

Comment: I understand entering it every time now but it asks me like 3-4 times. should it be doing that?

Comment: @Slayter please, read your tutorial carefully, it says: "If you leave this blank (not such good security) then no further typing of passphrases is needed."